# cp: cannot stat : No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, scp, cp

I am getting an error when I try to copy a file from my local computer to a remote server.  I get the same error whether I use `cp` or `scp`.

Here is my input at the resulting error:

```
[root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx /]# cp /home/username/some.xml root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:/path/to/directory/  
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/username/some.xml’: No such file or directory
```

I have checked, and there is definitely a file at the path `/home/username/some.xml` on my local machine.

Both the local computer and the remote server are running CentOS 7.  How can I resolve this error and copy successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have TWO problems.

**A**: you're apparently are on the machine you're trying to copy to, rather than the one you're trying to copy from

**B**: cp cannot transfer between machines.

To resolve **A** try

```
scp username@YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:/home/username/some.xml /path/to/directory/
```

Comment: My `cp` command in my OP above was correct with two minor modifications.  1.) I had to type `exit` to log out as `root@remote.server` and thus get a prompt on my local machine, and 2.) I had to change `cp` to `scp` in order to send the data to the remote web server.  Since your answer pointed me in the right direction, I am accepting, it, but the solution was what I am typing in this comment.  +1 for helping.